# does dojo config support requirejs bundles

Tags: dojo, requirejs

Does dojo config support [requirejs bundles](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-bundles)?

> Introduced in RequireJS 2.1.10: allows configuring multiple module IDs to be found in another script. Example:

```
requirejs.config({
    bundles: {
        'primary': ['main', 'util', 'text', 'text!template.html'],
        'secondary': ['text!secondary.html']
    }
});

require(['util', 'text'], function(util, text) {
    //The script for module ID 'primary' was loaded,
    //and that script included the define()'d
    //modules for 'util' and 'text'
});
```

> That config states: modules 'main', 'util', 'text' and 'text!template.html' will be found by loading module ID 'primary'. Module 'text!secondary.html' can be found by loading module ID 'secondary'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Dojo 1.8 modules were converted to AMD format, however dojo uses some "special loader plugins" which are still in draft and could be not fully compatible with RequireJS. On RequireJS documentation it is suggested to use Dojo's AMD loader instead.

Related doc from Dojod bug tracker [ticket 15616](https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/15616).

Please note in case you need to "build" your dojo application you should use [dojo util](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/util/) and `app.profile.js`,where you can specific a list of modules to "bundle" there.

I would suggest to have a look at this dojo-boilerplate as starting point for your dojo build configuration: https://github.com/csnover/dojo-boilerplate

A useful resource on the dojo build can be also found here: https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/build/

Comment: Thanks for the info, but I am trying to use dojo's amd loader.  What I'm trying to figure out is if the dojoConfig object supports the "bundles" property that the requirejs loader supports.

Comment: @MikeGraham As fair I know there is not such property on dojoConfig, no mention in documentation, if you need to bundle your dojo app you should instead use `util`. More info here https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/util/  and here: https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/_base/config.html